# Какую библиотеку, реализующую openGL лучше использовать для С#?

Tags: c#, opengl

Всем привет. 
Возник вопрос реализации нескольких приложений с использованием openGL на C#. До того игрался с openGL только на C++, и там определился с минимальным набором:

- glfw
- glew
- glm
- soil

Теперь пытаюсь найти аналогичные вещи и для C#. Посмотрел различные инструменты - их много, некоторые советуют, но они давно не обновлялись. Некоторые, напротив, не упоминаются в различных статьях - но зато обновляются.

В работе нужно будет реализовывать шейдеры, использовать много модельно-видовых преобразований. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, наиболее актуальный и удобный для этих задач стек библиотек.

Пока склоняюсь в пользу openTK, нежели TAO.

Comment: Ваш вопрос оффтопичен для so: он не имеет чётких критериев и его "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ".

Comment: под C# вроде openTK самое лучшее, так же умеет и в openCL Не знаю нужно ли тут работать с шейдерами, может лучше openGL + openCL?